# Scan through txt file, translate certain words found in dictionary [Python]

Tags: python, file, dictionary, cpu-word, translate

I have a file that contains this:

```
((S000383212:0.0,JC0:0.244562):0.142727,(S002923086:0.0,(JC1:0.0,JC2:0.0):0.19717200000000001):0.222151,((S000594619:0.0,JC3:0.21869):0.13418400000000003,(S000964423:0.122312,JC4:0.084707):0.18147100000000002):0.011521999999999977);
```

I have two dictionaries that contain:

```
org = {'JC4': 'a','JC0': 'b','JC1': 'c','JC2': 'c','JC3': 'd'}

RDP = {'S000383212': 'hello', 'S002923086': 'this', 'S000594619': 'is'}
```

**How would I find every time it says one of the words in one of the dictionaries and convert it to its alternative term?**

i.e. if it encounters 'JC0' then it would translate it to 'b'

Answer (score 5):

```
for key in org.keys() + RDP.keys():
    text = text.replace(key, org.get(key, None) or RDP.get(key, None))
```

Of course, as TryPyPy said, if you just merge the dicts, it becomes much simpler:

```
org.update(RDP)
for item in org.items():
    text = text.replace(*item)
```

Comment: If you create a dict merging org and RDP, getting the value becomes simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If the performance isn't very important you can use the following code:

```
with open('your_file_name.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    for key, value in org.items() + RDP.items():
        text = text.replace(key, value)
```

This code has the `O(n * k)` time complexity, where `n` is the length of the `text` and `k` is the count of entries in both dictionaries. If this complexity doesn't suit your task, the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) can help you.

Comment: You should either replace the first line with a `with... open():` or separate the `open` and `read` assignments. File closing isn't guaranteed without either a `with` or an explicit `close()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) string method.